# Confluence - Play a SWF on top of the page

Tags: javascript, flash, media, playback, confluence

I am not sure how to do this if I was working in a normal web coding environment, much less that I am working in Confluence.

My manager requests that our multimedia content on Confluence be able to play on top of a gray/semi transparent sheet that would appear on top of the page in the browser when the user clicks the link. I have seen this on several occasions on the web, where it puts the gray shape over the page, and a video with interface appears on over the page. There is usually some sort of X there to close it and return to the page you were browsing.

Searching for How-To's online, I found some tutorials for this but they require JavaScript or more, and as yet I have been unable to get Confluence to accept any script that I put onto a Confluence page. HTML and Confluence's own classes/macros seem to be my limitation.

Has anybody tried to do this with Confluence? My turnaround on this is expected to be fairly quick; I've explained that I'm not comfortable promising this because of my own limitations and those that I perceive in Confluence.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use javascript within Confluence you will need to go to edit -> administration -> Edit Layout. Within the layout editor, navigate to the JS tab. Here is where you add any javascript you want to use for the entire space. Trying to add javascript on a Confluence page itself won't work unless you're working within `{html}` tags, and even then I would recommend against having it on the page itself because you never know when you'll need to reuse that javascript on a different page.

Here is a page describing how to insert javascript on an individual page:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/How+to+Use+JavaScript+in+Confluence

And here is a page describing how to edit javascript in the JS tab of the layout editor:
http://www.adaptavist.com/display/Builder/JS+Tab